# Custom messages in different package - Is tutorial correct?

Tags: ros, package, custom-message, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In our system with >100 custom packages, there are >20 custom_msgs packages which provide for communication between packages. This question concerns correctly setting up CMakeLists.txt so the necessary messages get built before packages that depend on them.

The [Defining Custom Messages](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages) tutorial shows how to declare build and exec dependencies in package.xml, and also says you need to declare a build dependency on message_generation and an exec dependency on message_runtime - this all makes sense.

The tutorial states you need to add the following to CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(message_generation)
catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime)
add_message_files(FILES your_msg_file.msg)
```

**Is the last line correct?** I understand add_message_files is needed in the package that declares the messages, but is it really also needed in packages that use the messages in the custom_msgs package? That would imply that every package that uses a custom message would need to list the messages it uses - it doesn't seem right.

Does the last line need to be deleted from the tutorial?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289637/custom-messages-in-different-package---is-tutorial-correct?/) by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 300 on 2018-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, that is not correct.

`add_message_files(..)` only needs to be added to the build script of the package containing the messages.

Any consumers of the messages don't even interact with the `.msg` files themselves, only with the artefact generated from them (ie: source code / headers).

> Does the last line need to be deleted from the tutorial?

Yes.

I believe all those lines should be removed actually. Neither `message_generation`, nor `message_runtime` are needed in packages that only depend on pkgs that provide messages.

---

Edit: it would appear that all of those lines were added in [diff&rev1=19&rev2=20](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages?action=diff&rev1=19&rev2=20) (in 2015 !).

I'm also slightly confused by this tutorial: it's essentially the same content as [Creating a ROS msg and srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv). The only thing it adds is the fact that you can store messages, services and actions in a package by themselves (and it doesn't even really make that explicit). It also already links to the 'previous' tutorial.

I've always found the [catkin documentation](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html) on all of this much clearer and to-the-point.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) on 2018-04-25**:
Thanks for the confirmation @gvdhoorn. I didn't know whether to trust the catkin documentation you pointed to, but I see it has the add_dependencies(your_program ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}) that bit me so hard the other day. I think I will remove those 3 cmake lines and replace with EXPORTED_TARGETS

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-26**:
I would trust the catkin documentation over every tutorial on the wiki, any day.

Note: it's not just those "3 cmake lines" that need to go, the dependencies on `message_generation` and `message_runtime` are also completely unnecessary.

**Comment by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) on 2018-04-27**:
Fixed http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-27**:
np. Thanks for updating the tutorial.